# array.filter not specifying an argument when using but defined in function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am wondering if someone can explain to my why this is allowed more specifically why I don't need to say in `notes.filter(notesCheck)` what obj needs to be. The function works fine in this manner.

```
var duplicateNotes = notes.filter(notesCheck)

function notesCheck(obj) {
    if (obj.title === note.title) {
        console.log("duplicate found")
        return true
    }
}
```

I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter but didn't really gleam an explanation from it.

**Summary**
filter() calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which callback returns a value that coerces to true. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values. Array elements which do not pass the callback test are simply skipped, and are not included in the new array.

callback is invoked with three arguments:

the value of the element
the index of the element
the Array object being traversed

Comment: notesCheck is the callback function you supply, it will be called with three arguments for each iteration, the current item, current index, and the whole array

Comment: When you pass a defined function as a parameter, the parameters for the passed in function will be inferred from the definition.

Comment: Hey Jaromanda thanks I get that but its strange I can just pluck the current item out like that not needing to in some way say this is that I need

Comment: "When you pass a defined function as a parameter, the parameters for the passed in function will be inferred from the definition" so this is a common rule?

Comment: @gxminbdd that's not as much strange as its an elegant abstraction away from the rawness of indexed access :). Try implementing any of the `filter`, `map`, `reduce` functions yourself or find other people's implementations to understand the inner workings of these methods.

Comment: or did you find it explained in the functions documentation

Comment: Greato! thanks guys. its just something I haven't come across before but I now see its used by many different functions

Comment: I assume there will never be the case where there is more than one array object argument then

Comment: @gxminbdd think of it this way, you are simply replacing an anonymous function with a named function as the callback...so yes it is common and not specific to filter()

Answer (score 2):

`Array.filter` takes a function as input, and will call it for each element in the array. It works like:

```
var myFilter(array, test) {
  var result = [];
  array.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (test(obj)) { result.push(obj); }
  }
  return result;
}

// notes.filter(notesCheck) it the same as myFilter(notes, notesCheck)
```

So you don't need to specify the `obj` when calling filter, but just the logic to handle them.

Basically, `Array.filter(test)` means `give me all the elements that pass the test`, which in English I'm able to say without telling what are those elements, and so am I in javascript.

Comment: I think @nem035 is right: you'll learn quite a bit by implementing `filter`, `map`, `reduce` by yourself